# DialogFlow FulfillmentText doesn't appear in the chat Default Response

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks

I created a webhook for my agent, it works fine, I got a successful response from my webhook:

[image: Fulfillment Response]

But I got no response in the test chat:

[image: Default Response]

What I need to do to show it in the Default Response?

Answer (score 0):

I was sending the keys with PascalCase, I needed to use camelCase.
So I had to format the settings of the Json.

In Visual Studio (.NET Framework 4.5):

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };

return Json(response, jsonSerializer);
```

**Note:** In .NET Core, camelCase is default.